# ArcMap - How to create a grid in acres

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid, grids-graticules

In ArcMap, I need to depict points per acre as a layer on my map.

How do I create a grid layer with the grid cells equal to one acre?

My resolution is 1 meter.  I've been working with Fishnet and have put in a cell size of 64.

Is this the correct conversion?

Do I also need to put in number of rows and columns to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

There are ~4046.86 square meters in one acre, so if you take the square root you get ~63.6149353533 meters, which should match the dimensions of any side of the cells in your fishnet layer (assuming the cells are square). Using a value of 64m will produce cells that are over an acre by about 0.6%.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into programming you can accomplish this by creating a polygon shapefile, then using the coordinate system create your grid starting at the lower left corner and moving to the upper right corner.